# Cygwin SSH to Amazon EC2 Ubuntu hangs

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2, cygwin

I am trying to connect to a newly minted ubuntu instance on EC2 using a fresh install of Cygwin from Win 8 box, and now see my ssh connection hang without any error message.

I am just trying to connect to the instance like so;

```
ssh -vvvi xxx.pem ec2-user@xxx.compute.amazonaws.com
```

The .pem used to create the instance file is in the .ssh directory with the following (to my understanding ok) attributes;

```
$ ls -l
total 4
-r-------- 1 xxx Users 1696 Nov  3 11:38 xxx.pem
```

The connection starts and initial handshaking with the instance seems to happen, but then the connection just hangs without any real error message or timeouts. Detailed log below.

On the AWS side I just use the default security group which allows incoming on port 22 towards the instance.

Putty works fine after converting the .pem to the key format putty needs.

It's been ages since a did anything towards a Linux instance, and haven't had Cygwin 
installed in equally long, so I'm truly lost here.

Full output:

```
OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to xxx.compute.amazonaws.com [xx.xx.xx.xx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file xxx.pem.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug1: identity file xxx.pem type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.2p2 Ubuntu-6
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.2p2 Ubuntu-6 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.6
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: mac_init: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_init: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 112/256
debug2: bits set: 508/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /c/cygwin64/home/xxx/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /c/cygwin64/home/xxx/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /c/cygwin64/home/xxx/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
debug2: no key of type 0 for host xxx.compute.amazonaws.com
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /c/cygwin64/home/xxx/.ssh/known_hosts2
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /c/cygwin64/home/xxx/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
debug2: no key of type 2 for host xxx.compute.amazonaws.com
```

Nothing at all happens after the last debug message, no error, no timeout, no nothing...

Comment: It seems SSH is unable to understand your key file.

Comment: Yes, I'm suspecting something like that as well, there being something with the SSH client in the Cygwin install. There are, howvere, several google answers showing how to use cygwin to connect to an ubuntu EC2 without any problems, so I am a bit confused. Putty works fine btw, after converting the pem to a putty-compliant key.

Comment: What happens when you use "ssh -i [file.pem] ec2-user@hostname" dirrectly in a cygwin terminal "Mintty"?

Answer (score 0):

This will for sure work, it did for me and I have done it foe many others at work:
  **Make sure you launch cygwin as an admin**

1. Creat a folder inside cygwin that is viewable by the terminal called /.ssh
2. You can create a folder in windows with a dot by doing in command line        *mkdir .foldername*

   3.from outside of the folder execute this command : chgrp Users ~/.ssh/name_Of_The_Key.pem
3. *chmod 600 ~/.ssh/name_Of_The_Key.pem*
4. Connect to it.

Run command from within the .ssh folder

*ssh -i name_Of_The_Key.pem ubuntu@52.25.57.43*